# vscode multicursor reorder lines how to

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am finding a common issue I have with vscode multi-cursor editing mode is how to deal with "fields" of different lengths.  To give an example:-

I have an sql file which contains multiple lines of the form

```sql
INSERT INTO settings (name,value) VALUES('key_for_value', 'value_to_set'); -- a comment about this setting
```

Which I want to turn into

```sql
UPDATE settings SET name = 'value_to_set' WHERE name = 'key_for_value'; -- a comment about this setting
```

Obviously each `'key_for_value'` and `'value_to_set'` are different lengths in each line.

Its fairly easy to grab a bit of the first line of `INSERT INTO...` and with a control-D get multiple cursors from there, and edit the lines to to get to `UPDATE settings SET name =`  but then I am stuck - I can't find a key binding to (for instance) jump to the next comma - then start a selection and jump the next closing round bracket. I could then do a multiline cut, move the cursor back to start of line, more forward to after the `=` sign and do a multiline paste.

Is this sort of thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a regex search replace

Search for

```
INSERT INTO (\w+) \((\w+),(\w+)\) VALUES\('([^']+)', '([^']+)'\);(.*)
```

replace with

```
UPDATE $1 SET $2 = '$5' WHERE $2 = '$4';$6
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of a replace option, so neat.  However if there is a way to do it with multiple cursors I'd like to find out about that too.  I was hoping for something like jump to next word with select on, and then a column cut and paste, maybe through an extension.

Comment: @akc42 Ctrl+Arrow works for multi cursor but some characters break a word and then you get misalignment